# Palindrome generator

Tags: python, python-2.7, palindrome

Very inexperienced with python and programming in general.

I'm trying to create a function that generates a list of palindromic numbers up to a specified limit.

When I run the following code it returns an empty list [].  Unsure why this is so.

```
def palin_generator():
    """Generates palindromic numbers."""

    palindromes=[]
    count=0
    n=str(count)

    while count<10000:
        if n==n[::-1] is True:
            palindromes.append(n)
            count+=1
        else:
            count+=1

    print palindromes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if` statement does *not* do what you think it does.

You are applying operator chaining and you are testing 2 things:

```
(n == n[::-1]) and (n[::-1] is True)
```

This will *always* be `False` because `'0' is True` is not `True`. Demo:

```
>>> n = str(0)
>>> n[::-1] == n is True
False
>>> n[::-1] == n 
True
```

From the [comparisons documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).

You do *not* need to test for `is True` here; Python's `if` statement is perfectly capable of testing that for itself:

```
if n == n[::-1]:
```

Your next problem is that you never change `n`, so now you'll append 1000 `'0'` strings to your list.

You'd be better off using a `for` loop over `xrange(1000)` and setting `n` each iteration:

```
def palin_generator():
    """Generates palindromic numbers."""

    palindromes=[]

    for count in xrange(10000):
        n = str(count)
        if n == n[::-1]:
            palindromes.append(n)

    print palindromes
```

Now your function works:

```
>>> palin_generator()
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '11', '22', '33', '44', '55', '66', '77', '88', '99', '101', '111', '121', '131', '141', '151', '161', '171', '181', '191', '202', '212', '222', '232', '242', '252', '262', '272', '282', '292', '303', '313', '323', '333', '343', '353', '363', '373', '383', '393', '404', '414', '424', '434', '444', '454', '464', '474', '484', '494', '505', '515', '525', '535', '545', '555', '565', '575', '585', '595', '606', '616', '626', '636', '646', '656', '666', '676', '686', '696', '707', '717', '727', '737', '747', '757', '767', '777', '787', '797', '808', '818', '828', '838', '848', '858', '868', '878', '888', '898', '909', '919', '929', '939', '949', '959', '969', '979', '989', '999', '1001', '1111', '1221', '1331', '1441', '1551', '1661', '1771', '1881', '1991', '2002', '2112', '2222', '2332', '2442', '2552', '2662', '2772', '2882', '2992', '3003', '3113', '3223', '3333', '3443', '3553', '3663', '3773', '3883', '3993', '4004', '4114', '4224', '4334', '4444', '4554', '4664', '4774', '4884', '4994', '5005', '5115', '5225', '5335', '5445', '5555', '5665', '5775', '5885', '5995', '6006', '6116', '6226', '6336', '6446', '6556', '6666', '6776', '6886', '6996', '7007', '7117', '7227', '7337', '7447', '7557', '7667', '7777', '7887', '7997', '8008', '8118', '8228', '8338', '8448', '8558', '8668', '8778', '8888', '8998', '9009', '9119', '9229', '9339', '9449', '9559', '9669', '9779', '9889', '9999']
```

Answer (score 4):

Going through all numbers is quite inefficient. You can generate palindromes like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from itertools import count

def getPalindrome():
    """
        Generator for palindromes.
        Generates palindromes, starting with 0.
        A palindrome is a number which reads the same in both directions.
    """
    yield 0
    for digits in count(1):
        first = 10 ** ((digits - 1) // 2)
        for s in map(str, range(first, 10 * first)):
            yield int(s + s[-(digits % 2)-1::-1])

def allPalindromes(minP, maxP):
    """Get a sorted list of all palindromes in intervall [minP, maxP]."""
    palindromGenerator = getPalindrome()
    palindromeList = []
    for palindrome in palindromGenerator:
        if palindrome > maxP:
            break
        if palindrome < minP:
            continue
        palindromeList.append(palindrome)
    return palindromeList

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(allPalindromes(4456789, 5000000))
```

This code is much faster than the code above.

See also: [Python 2.x remarks](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/34059/4433).

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` block checks whether `n` is a palindrome, and the value of `n` never changes.  It's only assigned once.

Also, you can eliminate the `is True` part because that is redundant.

But that's not the root of your problem now.  In fact, the reason your `if` is failing is operator precedence.  What you've written now is equivalent to `if n==(n[::-1] is True):` which is `if n==False:`, which will never happen.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: True.  I added an explanation about `is`.